# Can ingestion of B6 cause gastrointestinal disturbance?

Tags: pharmacology

Can the ingestion of vitamin B6 upset the stomach, and if so by what mechanism?

Comment: Hi there. This question is seeking specific medical advice, and as such, is against our posting guidelines which specifically restricts medical diagnoses/advice. If you edit your question to remove the last sentence, then we would be happy to try to answer your question.

Comment: However, in **all cases** along these lines, see your doctor rather than the internet :)  There's a lot more to be safely gained through thorough history from a professional and clinical examination than through a question asked on a website

Comment: It is not reported anywhere that Vit B6/Pyridoxine has gastrointestinal side effects.